# How to make an asp website in fullscreen?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, fullscreen

I want to create a new web site, but I want it to display all pages in full screen mode and allow user to achieve desktop when this website running in one case only 
write a correct password.

my opinion is to create it as a single page , but I want another opinions .
how can I do this, any suggestions?

Comment: What?? I don't understand!

Comment: What you want is a **desktop** application, if you want to run it as a kiosk (fullscreen, unchangeable)

Comment: @cFrozenDeath  I aready have this application on desktop, and it works great , but I need to convert this app to website , why I can't do this?

Comment: @tym32167 why I can't do that?

Comment: @saraadly the main reason why you cant do that - security. If website was able to disable user with some screen which user cant remove, it will be security whole in browser. Website can do only suth things, which user allow to do.

Comment: @tym32167 I update question , please reread it

Comment: @saraadly you should understand. When you are working with website, not you allow something to user, but user allow something to you.You can not block anything. You cant enter fullscreen, only user can do that or allow to you that. User always can close you website without any propmpts/passwords.

Comment: You can't do this by browser , to do this you need to install service on client machine that capturing all event to prevent  change full screen event

Comment: [NodeWebkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) Might be a helpful library to help you achieve this.

Comment: Change this question to the same way as the other one... and see whats going on

Answer (score 3):

You are actually trying to go out of the bounds of the control of the browser and force something that you aren't allowed to. What would happen do you think when a malicious site could do that?

The best option you have now, is to use the [HTML5 Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), which leaves the control at the user to go out of full screen mode or deny your site to go to full screen mode, but still gives you as a developer the chance to build apps that are used in a sort of kiosk mode.

If you want to go further, you have to create a desktop application with full control over the OS.

Comment: So, what only I can do is a button to let user choose the mode he wants, fullscreen or not? is it right? and if I make that how can I make the all of website gets fullscreen?

Comment: Yes, something like that. See the linked MDN documentation page.

Comment: Sorry for being dummy, how can I use this api?

Comment: See the linked documentation. It has samples how to implement this.

Comment: `var isFullScreen = document.fullscreen;
            alert(isFullScreen);` it always gives me undefined

Comment: That means your browser does not support it.

Comment: Sorry for being as a pain, this api works when I use click but when I called it in onload it didn't response as `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            toggleFullScreen();
        });` but it works when I use `<input value="clic" type="button" onclick="toggleFullScreen()" />`  and function content is `function toggleFullScreen() {
            if (!document.webkitFullscreenElement) {                document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            } else { if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {document.webkitExitFullscreen(); } }
        }`

Comment: Maybe you should wait until the document has loaded. Not sure. Can you post a new question with the entire code you use?

Comment: I can't post a new Question because of all these down voted :( , any way thanks for your precious time I will give it more search